# how to evaluate a NSDictionary in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have a dictionary having two arrays, the dictionary is

```
NSDictionary * StudentDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:StudentIDs,StudentNames, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID",@"NAME", nil]];
```

and the two arrays are

```
NSArray * StudentIDs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"07bg1234",@"07ac1234", nil];
NSArray * StudentNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaaaaaa",@"bbbbb", nil];
```

and I tried predicates to retrieve array values as

```
NSString * searchStr = @"07bg1234";

    NSPredicate * fileExtPredicate01 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", StudentIDs];

    if (([fileExtPredicate01 evaluateWithObject: searchStr]== YES)) {
        NSLog(@"Student ID: %@ Exists",searchStr);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Student ID: %@ not Exists",searchStr);
    }
```

up to this it is working fine.... when i tried to get dictionary values as

```
NSPredicate * fileExtPredicate02 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", StudentDetails];

    if (([fileExtPredicate02 evaluateWithObject: searchStr]== YES)) {
        NSLog(@"Student Details: %@ Exists",searchStr);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Student Details: %@ not Exists",searchStr);
    }
```

I'm always getting the o/p as Student Details **** not Exists... How can i get the 'searchStr' is there or not in the dictionary using predicates???? Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Use `@"SELF IN %@.ID"`.

I build the following passing unit test.

```
NSArray * StudentIDs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"07bg1234",@"07ac1234", nil];
NSArray * StudentNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaaaaaa",@"bbbbb", nil];
NSDictionary * StudentDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:StudentIDs,StudentNames, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID",@"NAME", nil]];
NSString *searchStr = @"07bg1234";

NSPredicate * fileExtPredicate02 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@.ID", StudentDetails];

XCTAssert([fileExtPredicate02 evaluateWithObject:searchStr]);
```

---

**Update**

To get both ID an NAME, I used.

```
NSArray * StudentIDs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"07bg1234",@"07ac1234", nil];
NSArray * StudentNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaaaaaa",@"bbbbb", nil];
NSDictionary * StudentDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:StudentIDs,StudentNames, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID",@"NAME", nil]];

NSPredicate * fileExtPredicate02 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@.ID OR SELF IN %@.NAME", StudentDetails, StudentDetails];

XCTAssert([fileExtPredicate02 evaluateWithObject:@"07bg1234"]);
XCTAssert([fileExtPredicate02 evaluateWithObject:@"aaaaaaa"]);
```

This feels very kludgy to me, and I think there is a better answer using `SUBQUERY()`, but I'll have to think about that a bit more.

---

**Update 2**

So if you can put up with some wonkiness, here is the `SUBQUERY()` version. The predicate is `SUBQUERY(%@, $value, SELF IN $value).@count > 0`. `SUBQUERY(%@, $value, SELF IN $value)` returns an array of matching values and `.@count > 0` returns true if there is at least 1 match. Unlike the previous sample, I don't pass `StudentDetails`. I need to pass `StudentDetails.allValues`.

```
NSArray * StudentIDs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"07bg1234",@"07ac1234", nil];
NSArray * StudentNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaaaaaa",@"bbbbb", nil];
NSDictionary * StudentDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:StudentIDs,StudentNames, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID",@"NAME", nil]];

NSPredicate * fileExtPredicate02 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(%@, $value, SELF IN $value).@count > 0", StudentDetails.allValues];

XCTAssert([fileExtPredicate02 evaluateWithObject:@"07bg1234"]);
XCTAssert([fileExtPredicate02 evaluateWithObject:@"aaaaaaa"]);
```

Comment: the searchStr may be either in ID or in NAME. The above code suggesting to restrict the search, searchStr to check in ID only.. but i have to check the value in entire dictionary

Comment: @Sunil sorry that wasn't clear in your question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: sorry for that.. but i mentioned as " How can i get the 'searchStr' is there or not in the dictionary using predicates "..... in that i can change the searchStr as my wish right as value of ID or value of NAME

Comment: @Sunil I created a different answer using `SUBQUERY`. Hopefully one of them will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

For a dictionary you need the condition `<Item> IN <Key>` which corresponds to `@"07bg1234" IN @"ID"` in your example. The object in `evaluateWithObject` is the dictionary.

```
NSPredicate *fileExtPredicate02 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN ID", searchStr];
if ([fileExtPredicate02 evaluateWithObject: studentDetails] == YES) {
  NSLog(@"Student Details: %@ Exists",searchStr);
}
else {
  NSLog(@"Student Details: %@ not Exists", searchStr);
};
```

Comment: if searchStr is the value in StudentIDs it is Ok.. if the searchStr is the value in StudentNames it does not work.. In the Predicate assignment you have not mentioned dictionary?? is only key value enough????

Comment: Of course for items in `StudentNames` is the key `NAME`

Comment: the searchStr may be either in ID or in NAME. The above code suggesting to restrict the searchStr to ID... I have an idea that does not restrict the searchStr but it needs one more predicate.. As the Dictionary contains n number of Arrays, I have to create n number of predicates... is there any other way in simple format